# jquery + populate field in same row when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement, that on checking a box, populates the input in that same row with a value.

My code is:

```
function populatetransportprice() {
// iterate through the "checked" checkboxes
$("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]:checked').each(function () {
    alert(treatedtransportcostperton);
    row.find('input[name^="transportprice"]').val(treatedtransportcostperton.toFixed(2));
});
```

}

The input field for each row is `tranpsortpriceX` where X is the row number.

My HTML is:

```
<table class="authors-list" id="ordertable">
<tr>
 <td><input name="transportprice1" id="transportprice1" class="rounded"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input name="transportprice2" id="transportprice2" class="rounded"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input name="transportprice3" id="transportprice3" class="rounded"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The alert populates for each checked box in the table however the input is not populated.
I assume its with my `row.find`.

any advice appreciated,
Thanks

**Update**

current syntax:

```
 function populatetransportprice() {
$("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]:checked').each(function () {
 $(this).find('input[name^="transportprice"]').val(treatedtransportcostperton.toFixed(2));
$(this).next('input[name^="transportprice"]').val(treatedtransportcostperton.toFixed(2));
});    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to give you an accurate answer without also seeing the markup that this effects.

However, from the limited details you have given us I would expect that the reason this isn't working is your `row` variable.

We don't have the rest of the code that shows how this is set, however my suspicion would be that `row` isn't set properly, or isn't referencing the element you think it is.

Your best bet would be to set `row` within your `each` so that you can ensure you're targetting the row relevant to the input.

Something like:

```
function populatetransportprice() {
// iterate through the "checked" checkboxes
$("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]:checked').each(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        priceInput = row.find('input[name^="transportprice"]');

    alert(treatedtransportcostperton);
    priceInput.val(treatedtransportcostperton.toFixed(2));
});
```

This assumes that the 'row' is indeed a table-row `tr`.

Comment: Thanks johnkavanagh, 100% on the money. works great. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

the 'row' is not defined anywhere.

```
    $("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="treated"]:checked').each(function () {
        alert(treatedtransportcostperton);
//Try $(this) instead of row. Here 'this' implies each and every element in the loop and then it finds within the element. I think the following code might help,
     $(this).find('input[name^="transportprice"]').val(treatedtransportcostperton.toFixed(2));
$(this).next('input[name^="transportprice"]').val(treatedtransportcostperton.toFixed(2));
//the above is an assumption. Post your HTML
    });
```

Comment: Thanks aravindtrue, appreciate it man. this doesn't work currently. will edit question with HTML now. Thanks